# C++: Singleton class template causes linking error?

Tags: c++, templates, linker, singleton

I tried to make a singleton (base) class:

```
template<typename SUBCLASS>
class Singleton {
public:
    static SUBCLASS& get_instance() {
        static SUBCLASS instance;
        return instance;
    }
};
```

This singleton class is in a header file, which can be included by any other file. E.g. a class could look like this:

```
class MyClass : public Singleton<MyClass> {
public:
...
private:
    MyClass() {
    }

    friend Singleton<MyClass>;
}
```

Somewhere else `MyClass` can be used like this:

```
MyClass& instance = MyClass::get_instance();
```

The good point: Compilation works.
The bad point: Linking fails.

The error message is:

```
undefined reference to `MyClass::get_instance()'
```

What do i do wrong? Has anyone a hint?

Thank youvery much

best regards

Kevin

Comment: What compiler are you using? It works for me in Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: For me this code compiles and linkes with no problems beside MyClass::MyClass() needs to be public. Are all source files part of the build? Is this class belongs to a monolith executable or is shifted to a library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `using` keyword:

```
class MyClass : public Singleton<MyClass> {
public:
    using Singleton<MyClass>::get_instance;
...
private:
    MyClass() {
    }

    friend Singleton<MyClass>;
}
```

This pulls the function in into the scope of `MyClass`.

Comment: is this needed because `get_istance` is static?

Comment: @bolov Yes, because it's static it isn't "inherited", it will always be static in the base class.

Answer (score 1):

During the compilation, unreferenced static methods may be omitted. You can fix this either by referencing the method in the same compilation unit, or by altering optimization settings, specific to your compiler.

Another way may be to explicitly instantiate your template, like this:

```
template class Singleton<MyClass>;
```

Answer (score 1):

Compiles fine for me.

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename SUBCLASS>
class Singleton {
public:
    static SUBCLASS& get_instance() {
        static SUBCLASS instance;
        return instance;
    }
};

class MyClass : public Singleton<MyClass> {
public:

private:
    MyClass() {
    }

    friend Singleton<MyClass>;
};

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    MyClass& a = MyClass::get_instance();
    return 0;
}
```

compile with:

`c++ singleton.cpp`

Comment: I use for each class (and also the main) a seperate compilation unit, probably this causes the problems.